# Add a new line to .txt file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, txt

I have the following .txt file:

```
0   40  50  0   0   1236 0  0   0
1   45  70  -20 825 870 90  3   0
2   42  68  -10 727 782 90  4   0
3   40  69  20  621 702 90  0   1
4   38  70  10  534 605 90  0   2
5   25  85  -20 652 721 90  11  0
6   22  75  30  30  92  90  0   10
7   22  85  -40 567 620 90  9   0
8   20  80  -10 384 429 90  12  0
9   20  85  40  475 528 90  0   7
10  18  75  -30 99  148 90  6   0
11  15  75  20  179 254 90  0   5
12  15  80  10  278 345 90  0   8
```

I need to copy the first line and add it to the .txt file as last line in order to get this:

```
0   40  50  0   0   1236 0  0   0
1   45  70  -20 825 870 90  3   0
2   42  68  -10 727 782 90  4   0
3   40  69  20  621 702 90  0   1
4   38  70  10  534 605 90  0   2
5   25  85  -20 652 721 90  11  0
6   22  75  30  30  92  90  0   10
7   22  85  -40 567 620 90  9   0
8   20  80  -10 384 429 90  12  0
9   20  85  40  475 528 90  0   7
10  18  75  -30 99  148 90  6   0
11  15  75  20  179 254 90  0   5
12  15  80  10  278 345 90  0   8
13  40  50  0   0   1236 0  0   0
```

How can I do that? (Notice the 13 as the first entry of the last line)

Comment: How exactly are you deciding what goes into the last line?

Comment: There are several possible ways to do this, was there a particular problem with the attempts you have made so far?

Comment: The added line is the same as the first one however the first entry of this last line has to be 13

Comment: So far I could only add the new line as a copy of the first one; however, I cannot manage to change the first entry to 13 (which actually is my new line number)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
  with open('fileName.txt') as file:
      first_line = file.readline()
      count = sum(1 for _ in file)
      line1 = first_line.split()
      line1[0] = count
      str = ' '.join(line1)
      #then you can add it to the end of the file with: 
      file_object.write(str)
```

Comment: Exactly! However, consider the first column as the line number (from 0 to how many lines I have). Therefore, I need to update my new line number for the added line to 13. I am stuck there

Comment: I edited the code, can you see if this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. I have added some comments to describe the steps

```
with open('yourfile.txt') as f:
    t=f.readlines()
    row=t[-1].split()[0] #get the last row index 
    row=str(int(row)+1) #increase the last row index
    new_line=t[0] #copy first line
    new_line=new_line.replace('0', row, 1).replace(' ', '',len(row)-1) #add the next row index to new line, taking care of spaces
    t[-1]=t[-1]+'\n'
    t.append(new_line) #append the new line

with open('yourfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(t)
```

Applied to your existing .txt, result of the above code is:

```
0   40  50  0   0   1236 0  0   0
1   45  70  -20 825 870 90  3   0
2   42  68  -10 727 782 90  4   0
3   40  69  20  621 702 90  0   1
4   38  70  10  534 605 90  0   2
5   25  85  -20 652 721 90  11  0
6   22  75  30  30  92  90  0   10
7   22  85  -40 567 620 90  9   0
8   20  80  -10 384 429 90  12  0
9   20  85  40  475 528 90  0   7
10  18  75  -30 99  148 90  6   0
11  15  75  20  179 254 90  0   5
12  15  80  10  278 345 90  0   8
13  40  50  0   0   1236 0  0   0
```